# Throttling curl_multi_exec to 3-4 processes instead of all of them without exiting loop

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

I seem to be crashing my website by asking for too many connections at once (600~),
I would like to throttle this back to maybe 3-4 connections, sleep till free, then add more as needed.

The code that I was thinking about using is...

```
// execute the handles
$running = null;
do
{

    if ($running <= 4) curl_multi_exec($mh, $running); //add handle

    usleep(100); //sleep 

} while($running > 0);
```

I do NOT think this is the right/sane way to do this though, can someone recommend a better way please?

Comment: Actually, it's kind of fine.  Instead of using a count though, establish a queue, pull a batch size off the queue, and keep that batch full until all the queue is drained.  Implementation example: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/

Comment: Plus 1, thanks Bishop I'll read into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Native Solutions in PHP 5.5

There is an option for limiting the number of connections in PHP >= 5.5 using `curl_multi_setopt` and the `CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS` option.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-setopt.php

**CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS**
Pass a number that will be used as the maximum amount of simultaneously open connections that libcurl may cache. Default is 10. When the cache is full, curl closes the oldest one in the cache to prevent the number of open connections from increasing.

e.g.:

```
curl_multi_setopt ( $mh , CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 4);
```

*Caveats - there are reported stability issues on CentOS, and PHP 5.5 or above is required.*

### **In answer to your question about sanity**:

The way you are doing it is sane in principle... but can get stuck in an infinite loop very easily.

Appreciate that `$running` is only updated when *`curl_multi_exec($mh, $running)`* is called because $running is passed as  a reference variable to curl_multi_exec;

### **Solutions**

Try these free libraries which achieve what you want to do in an easy-to-swallow format.

1. RollingCURL: https://github.com/takinbo/rolling-curl
2. Guzzle - using Pools:  http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests

Both of which are well tested and have built in maximum connection capabilities.